# CSS Question - Any way to set (eg. a font-size) to a group of styles, by linking the style to another?

Tags: css, stylesheet

.small_fonts{ font-size:10px; }

.fonts_blue{ color:blue; }
.fonts_red{ color:red; }
.fonts_green{ color:green; }

Any way to apply "small_fonts" to each of the "fonts_blue, _red, _green" w/o doing this:

.fonts_blue, fonts_red, fonts_green { font-size:10px; }

I am just trying to update my css to be more organized. I realised I don't need to define the font-size for each of the "small" fonts.

When adding the class btw... I know you can do this: class="small_fonts fonts_blue" ~ however I'm talking about combining within the css stylesheet

Comment: just an aside, but class names like `fonts_blue` defines how it looks and not the role or function of the element. if 6 months down the road you decide the items with `fonts_blue` should be bold and green, then either your css is going to be really weird or your html is gonna have to change. Generally it is a better practice to separate your style from your content by sticking to classes like `article` or `footer` and using css definitions like `.article h2` for article headings -- just as an example.

Comment: Thanks you're right. I have this issue already, where I want to port my css to another website and the colors are all different. I then adapted "maincolor" instead of "blue".

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in raw CSS.

You may want to take a look at CSS preprocessors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: I wouldn't know how to apply SASS for typical setups like my own where I use apache/linux (no rails).

Comment: @Joe - neither SASS nor LESS are tied to rails or ruby at runtime. You do need to have ruby to process the stylesheet (though for LESS there's a PHP port: http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/) but once preprocessed they become regular CSS files.

Comment: I was just about to do it using PHP and save a cached css file, however it looks like this is already done for me with that port. Great!

Answer (score 1):

SASS may be able to achieve this:

http://sass-lang.com/

'Sass is a meta-language on top of CSS that’s used to describe the style of a document cleanly and structurally, with more power than flat CSS allows. Sass both provides a simpler, more elegant syntax for CSS and implements various features that are useful for creating manageable stylesheets.'